# Align an href img top left regardless of DTD, browser

Tags: html, css

How would I go about having a `href` image fixed at the `top left` of a page without stuffing up any content in the current webpage and act pretty much exactly the same regardless of browser and DTD.

The problem I have is I need to supply a block of code to various websites that puts the said image in the same place so someone can easily click through.

I assume I am going to have contain everything within a `DIV`.

```
  <div style="position: absolute;left:0px;top:0px;">
    <a href="some.link.com">
      <img src="someimage.jpg" alt="someimage">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Or is that as good as it gets?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it fixed, i suppose you should use "position:fixed" property.. no?
And maybe z-index will be useful for you too (to place div on the highest layer, then other content).

As i understand, you would like to provide some HTML to some users that will add it to their own websites (or to add it by yourself, like ADS). If i am right, you should also think about other css properties, that are not defined in your div, but that can be defined on different websites (i mean margins, paddings, etc) in css, and will be automatically applied to your div.

Comment: It's not an add it's a link to a menu. But yeah, CSS already in the document is more what I am worried about, trying to circumvent.